# Get data from Google Search Console URL Inspector API with python

Tags: python, google-api-client, google-search-console

I want to request data from the Google Search Console URL Inspector API.
See documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v1/urlInspection.index/inspect?hl=de)

I tried to build the service with `googleapiclient` library and the build method:

```
 build(
   'searchconsole',
   'v1',
   credentials = credentials,
 discoveryServiceUrl = 'https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlInspection/index:inspect')
```

But I get the error:

> UnknownApiNameOrVersion: name: searchconsole  version: v1

Does anyone know, what the correct name of the API is? I am pretty sure, that the version is correct.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the PySearchConsole library [ pip install pysearchconsole ] to solve all of the above problems. Make sure that you have obtained the credentials.json file. Please note that the refresh token for this library expires after 6 months of inactivity. If you use the library before the expiration date, the expiration time gets extended to another 6 months.